# NGINX access logs from Single Page Application (SPA) and CMS

Tags: nginx, content-management-system, single-page-application, nginx-log

We have a frontend Angular app of Single Page Application and CMS design, where which is hosted in a docker container based on NGINX. The config is simply as below.

The problem is that the access log only writes logs when the whole page is refreshed and not in each user action (ie click different elements of the page).

We want to be able to log every user action, not only when the page is opened or refreshed.

We are not sure if the problem is the SPA or CMS design.

This works as expected with other pages that are designed differently.

```
events{}
http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```